Use case for integrating Chocolatey with SCCM
System Center Configuration Manager seems to have the features for publishing packaged applications so that employees of an enterprise can install applications from a central repository using the Software Center application installed on Windows. I see articles on the internet that state that Chocolatey has an integration with SCCM but do not explicitly state the precise use case wherein this integration is required. Can anyone suggest why one might need Chocolatey to work with SCCM?
